# Python pandas read_csv is printing time, not loading file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure why, but when I use Python `pandas.read_csv`, it is not opening a csv file, instead it is printing out UTC (as if from `time.time()`).

What would make this happen?

The commands I am running are:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("testfile.csv", delimiter=",", header=None)
```

The test file is any csv I try to open.

Edit: To clarify the behaviour, when I run the command, the program goes into a non ending loop, as if the following was run:

```
while True:
    print(time.time())
    time.sleep(a few seconds)
```

Comment: @jezrael, I don’t think that’s what’s happening. I clarified what is happening in my question.

Comment: @jezrael, I’m sure why. It initially started happening after I copied a file from my raspberry pi to my PC. That program was saving UTC times to the file. But now it happens with any file.

Comment: I think this is [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @jezrael. Also, this is on Ubuntu Linux, I was also copying a deleting a large amount of data (100 GB) from my hard disk at the same time as doing this.

Comment: @jezrael, how is it an XY problem?

Comment: I guess, because no idea.